# Webpack react app proxying to express server. Returning the json response from the express server rather than react components

Tags: reactjs, express, networking, webpack

I have a react web app that uses express as the back end.

I have it set up so that it proxies the request urls on the react server port (9000), to the express  server (3000). Problem is, when I type in the path /examplepath, it returns the json that the express app returns, rather than returning the component that renders from getting that response from the backend. I am getting the express response and looking at it rather than react getting the express response and looking at it and then rendering and showing me that render.

[When I click this button, it renders the correct page because it uses this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WLTN.png)

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.post('/', qs.stringify(this.state))
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data === "session") {
        this.setState({session: true})
      }
    })
  }
```

[It will render the page correctly using react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLdRH.png)

But if I visit the route directly it renders the json response from the express backend.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIBTD.png)

When I want it to render like the correcly rendered one using react

```
  devServer: {
    port: 9000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '/': 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
  }
```

THIS ^ is my webpack.config.js

Comment: The Issue is still not solved btw

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `historyApiFallback: true` to your `webpack.config.js` file (not sure if the proxy will mess with it -- if so, use express [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) middleware on the backend instead):

```
devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9000,
    quiet: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
```

Also, a more common port setup is: React app on `3000` and API/server on `5000`.

In addition, make sure you clearly separate your front and back end routes. Try keeping your back end routes to `/api/someurl`, and adding that to your proxy (and `AJAX` requests):

```
proxy: {
      '/api/*': 'http://localhost:3000/api/'
    }
```

Then, all front-end requests will be:

```
axios.get('/api/someurl').then().catch()
```

which will resolve to `http://localhost:3000/api/someurl`. This way, there's no chance of blending the front and back end routes.

Personally, I'd recommend `cors` over a `proxy`, because the proxy has been known to cause random [connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483349/econnrefused-error-for-create-react-app-and-node-server).

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I'll try this and let you know if it works

Comment: See updated comment. If you're still having problems, then post a link to your github repo and I can run/diagnose the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/andrew-linck/TourneyStack I did both those things you described. I have cors on my express server. Also i tried adding api to the express server routes. Nothing worked. I never added cors to the react side. Not sure if that would help. Also I put directions on how to set it up for debugging in the Read.MD. You will need a riot games account and use it to log in to get the api key. Riot account is just email and password I believe

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at it tomorrow and see what I can do.

Comment: Props to this guy. He really helped me out alot and asked for nothing but a thanks. He really cares about the open source community and I appreciate him. Thanks Matt