# React + Express on Azure: Invalid Host Header

Tags: reactjs, azure, express, docker

### The Error

When deploying to Azure Web Apps with Multi-container support, I receive an **"Invalid Host Header"** message from https://mysite.azurewebsites.com

### Local Setup

This runs fine.

I have two Docker containers: `client` a React app and `server` an Express app hosting my API. I am using a proxy to host my API on `server`.

In `client`'s package.json I have defined:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
```

I use the following docker compose file to build locally.

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    expose:
      - ${APP_SERVER_PORT}
    environment:
      API_HOST: ${API_HOST}
      APP_SERVER_PORT: ${APP_SERVER_PORT}
    ports: 
      - ${APP_SERVER_PORT}:${APP_SERVER_PORT}
    volumes: 
      - ./server/src:/app/project-server/src
    command: npm start

  client: 
    build: ./client
    environment: 
      - REACT_APP_PORT=${REACT_APP_PORT}
    expose:
      - ${REACT_APP_PORT}
    ports:
      - ${REACT_APP_PORT}:${REACT_APP_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./client/src:/app/project-client/src
      - ./client/public:/app/project-client/public
    links:
      - server
    command: npm start
```

Everything runs fine.

### On Azure

When deploying to Azure I have the following. `client` and `server` images have been stored in Azure Container Registry. They appear to load just fine from the logs.

In my App Service > Container Settings I am loading the images from Azure Container Registry (ACR) and I'm using the following configuration (Docker compose) file.

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  client: 
    image: <clientimage>.azurecr.io/clientimage:v1
    build: ./client
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: npm start

  server:
    image: <serverimage>.azurecr.io/<serverimage>:v1
    build: ./server
    expose:
      - 3001
    ports: 
      - 3001:3001
    command: npm start
```

I have also defined in Application Settings:

`WEBSITES_PORT` to be 3000.

This results in the error on my site **"Invalid Host Header"**

### Things I've tried

• Serving the app from the `static` folder in `server`. This works in that it serves the app, but it messes up my authentication. I need to be able to serve the static portion from `client`'s App.js and have that talk to my Express API for database calls and authentication.

• In my docker-compose file binding the front end to:

```
ports:
 - 3000:80
```

• A few other port combinations but no luck.

Also, I think this has something to do with the `proxy` in `client`'s package.json based on [this repo](https://github.com/LucMurakami/myWebsite#invalid-host-header-errors-after-configuring-proxy)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### Update

It is the proxy setting.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845805/deploying-create-react-app-to-heroku-with-express-backend-returns-invalid-host-h) somewhat solves it. By removing `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` I am able to load the website, but the suggested answer in the problem does not work for me. i.e. I am now unable to access my API.

Answer (score 0):

Never used `azure` before and I also don't use a proxy (due to its [random connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483349/econnrefused-error-for-create-react-app-and-node-server)), but if your application is basically running `express`, you can utilize [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors). (As a side note, it's more common to run your express server on `5000` than `3001`.)

I first set up an **env/config.js** folder and file like so:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    database: 'mongodb://localhost/boilerplate-dev-db',
    port: 5000,
    portal: 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
  production: {
    database: 'mongodb://localhost/boilerplate-prod-db',
    port: 5000,
    portal: 'http://example.com',
  },
  staging: {
    database: 'mongodb://localhost/boilerplate-staging-db',
    port: 5000,
    portal: 'http://localhost:3000',
  }
};
```

Then, depending on the environment, I can implement `cors` where I'm defining express middleware:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const config = require('./path/to/env/config.js');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

app.use(
    cors({
      credentials: true,
      origin: config[env].portal,
    }),
  );
```

Please note the portal and the `AJAX` requests MUST have matching host names. For example, if my application is hosted on `http://example.com`, my front-end API requests must be making requests to `http://example.com/api/` (not `http://localhost:3000/api/` -- [click here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Matts-Universe/blob/development/client/src/actions/axiosConfig.js) to see how I implement it for my website), and the `portal` env must match the host name `http://example.com`. This set up is flexible and necessary when running multiple environments.

Or if you're using the `create-react-app`, then simply eject your app and implement a [proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) inside the `webpack` production configuration.

Or migrate your application to my [fullstack boilerplate](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Webpack-React-Boilerplate/tree/fullstack), which implements the `cors` example above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm still exploring options here, so I will post when I have a working solution.

Comment: Perhaps this is another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619644/i-am-getting-an-invalid-host-header-message-when-running-my-react-app-in-a-we

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up having to move off of containers and serve the React app up in more of a typical MERN architecture with the Express server hosting the React app from the static build folder. I set up some routes with PassportJS to handle my authentication.

Not my preferred solution, I would have preferred to use containers, but this works. Hope this points someone out there in the right direction!